# GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault() does not return GCE instance credential

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am running a Java application on GCE. I am trying to get the Google Cloud Credentials from this instance to use in my application. When running on GCE, the credential returned is not the instance credential even though I am using the application default credential. This is my code in its entirety:

```
package test;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.util.Utils;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpTransport transport = Utils.getDefaultTransport();
        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(transport, Utils.getDefaultJsonFactory());
        credential = credential.createScoped(Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"));
        System.out.println(credential.getServiceAccountId());
    }
}
```

My gradle file:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
targetCompatibility = '1.8'

project.mainClassName = 'test.Test'

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.google.api-client', name: 'google-api-client', version: '1.22.0'
}
```

I've built this into a distribution using the `:assembleDist` gradle target. I've copied the assembled distribution over to a GCE instance. The result of `gcloud auth list` is:

```
Credentialed Accounts:
 - ##########-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com ACTIVE
To set the active account, run:
    $ gcloud config set account `ACCOUNT`
```

When I run my code, the output is:

```
java -jar test-1.0-all.jar 
null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the "userinfo.email" scope was not present on the machine. This scope will never be present when selecting "Allow full access to Cloud APIs" during instance creation. Seems like a bug on Google's end.